# Firefox "Not Responding" on Windows 7 because of Flash?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 64-bit, flash, freeze

Since I've been using Firefox on my 64-bit Windows machine, every few minutes the browser stops responding, with "Not Responding" in the title bar and the screen fades out for a few seconds.

I've googled this issue, and it appears other users are experiencing this too, with some suggestions that it's caused by the Flash plugin. I don't want to disable Flash, because I like to watch videos, so is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: The flash problem is not only in Firefox, I have noticed after installing flash lagging occures frequently, I only enable falsh when it is needed, I use IE mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the latest version of Firefox (3.6.x), it splits Flash (and other plugins) into a separate process called "plugin-container.exe" that you can see in Task Manager separately from the main firefox.exe process, do you see that using a lot of resources when your Firefox freezes?

If not, then this may not directly be Flash freezing the browser.

(On another note, I have Flash and 32-bit Firefox running happily on 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise and don't see these freezes)

**Update in 2014**

These days Mozilla have some knowledgebase pages on troubleshooting problems with the Flash plugin [Adobe Flash plugin has crashed - Prevent it from happening again](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/adobe-flash-plugin-has-crashed) | [Flash video won't play full screen on YouTube, Facebook and other websites](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/flash-video-wont-play-full-screen). Though what fixed recent Flash not responding problems for me with Flash 13 on Windows 7 was [Disabling Protected Mode in Flash 11.3](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Flash#Disabling_Protected_Mode_in_Flash_11.3).

The last resort option (that I followed) in Adobe's FAQ [How do I troubleshoot Flash Player's protected mode for Firefox?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4468493) is:

> **Last resort**
>
> Finally, if these problems are blocking you from using Flash Player we recommend, as a last resort, you either revert back to Flash Player 11.2 or temporarily disable Protected Mode.  We strongly recommend that Protected Mode is manually enabled once this issue is resolved.
>
> To revert to a previous version of Flash Player, please see this FAQ: [How do I revert to a previous version of Flash Player?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1022066?tstart=0)
>
> To disable Protected Mode, add the following line to your mms.cfg file located in:
>
> Windows 32bit: C:\windows\system32\macromed\flash
>
> Windows 64bit: C:\windows\syswow64\macromed\flash
>
> `ProtectedMode=0`
>
> If the mms.cfg file does not exist, create one using any standard text editor (e.g.. notepad)
>
> Depending on your operating system, you might need to first save the mms.cfg file to a writable location (such as your documents or desktop folder) and then copy the file into the destination folder using Windows Explorer.
>
> To re-enable Protected Mode, simply remove the line from the mms.cfg file.

Comment: yeah further investigation across the web is suggesting that this is a deeper problem than Flash. Resource Monitor is reporting that "One or more threads of firefox.exe is waiting to finish network I/O". But with that said, I wonder why this issue seems to manifest itself after I activate Flash. I don't recall trouble like this with IE6 on XP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Adobe has got a [special website](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html) about this problem. You will need to install and use a 32-bit browser to resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm already using 32-bit firefox though.. so I don't think this is it

Comment: so, maybe it isn´t the browser with flash causing the problem after all. Or is the problem gone if you disable flash for testing purposes?